# How to add a column to a line in a cvs file for later processing in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a bash script that is processing orders that are stored in a CSV file to generate product documentation to be emailed to the customers at a later time. My problem is that my script is currently emailing each of the products out as they are generated instead of storing each customer's full order in one line of a CSV file for processing by an email script after I have uploaded the upload CSV file.

I have tried using array(), awk, seg but those are not working the way I want.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
csvFile=$wdir/$1
csvfileup=$wdir/product/upload_$yr-$mo-$dy_$hr-$mn-$sc.csv
# create header in upload cvs file
echo "name;sku;description;category_1;category_2;category_3;image_url;weight;price;compair_to_price;quantity;enabled;UPC;brand;page_title;meta_description" >> $csvfileup
#function to generate files based off of information retrieved from a csv file
fun_genfiles(){
        cd $wdir/product/$3
        max=$(($countl + $1))
        while [ $count -lt $max ]; do
            count=$((++count))
            nval=<serial number generation>
            cp $wdir/$srcfile $wdir/product/$3/$2$nval.pdf
            echo $3/$2$nval
            echo <product information> >> $csvfileup
            #mailx -A $2$nval.pdf --content-type=text/html -s "Here is non-registered copy $count of the product." --return-address=<return@medomain.com> < ~/Downloads/commandlinesending/mail.txt $4
        done
        countl=$max
        #echo $countl
    }
#read Cvs File and call fun_genfiles with the proper values according to the type of order placed

while read -r line
do
    field1=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $3}' | tr -d '"')
    field2=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $16}' | tr -d '"')
    field3=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $15}' | tr -d '"')
    field4=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $2}' | tr -d '"')
    echo $field1 $field2 $field3 $field4
# Generate 
    if [ $field1 = "Product 1" ]; then
        mkdir $wdir/product/$field2
        cp $wdir/$srcfile $wdir/product/$field2/$field2.pdf
        echo <master copy information> >> $csvfileup
        #cd $wdir/product/$field2
        #mailx -A $field2.pdf --content-type=text/html -s "Here is your personal copy of Product 1." --return-address=<return@medomain.com> < ~/Downloads/commandlinesending/mail.txt $field4
        fun_genfiles 21 "PD1" $field2 $field4 $field3
    elif [ $field1 = "Product 2" ]; then
        mkdir $wdir/product/$field2
        cp $wdir/$srcfile $wdir/product/$field2/$field2.pdf
        echo <master copy information> >> $csvfileup
        #cd $wdir/product/$field2
        #mailx -A $field2.pdf --content-type=text/html -s "Here is your personal copy of Product 2." --return-address=<return@medomain.com> < ~/Downloads/commandlinesending/mail.txt $field4
        fun_genfiles 21 "PD2" $field2 $field4 $field3
    elif [ $field1 = "Product 3" ]; then
        mkdir $wdir/product/$field2
        cp $wdir/$srcfile $wdir/product/$field2/$field2.pdf
        echo <master copy information> >> $csvfileup
        #cd $wdir/product/$field2
        #mailx -A $field2.pdf --content-type=text/html -s "Here is your personal copy of Product 3." --return-address=<return@medomain.com> < ~/Downloads/commandlinesending/mail.txt $field4
        fun_genfiles 21 "PD3" $field2 $field4 $field3
    fi
done < $csvFile
```

What I am expecting is that the email.csv file that is generated as a single line for each order with the first column being the email address and columns 2 - product count is each serial number of the order. With what I have had for output is the email CSV file has what should be on one line for each order is actually on multiple lines instead.

Edit :

The mailx and sleep lines will be deleted as those lines are going into a different script and they are the only thing that slows the processing down.

Here is the header line and a couple of sample lines of the downloaded order.csv:

```
order_number,email,SKU,name,<....>,payment_method,<....>,customer_ipaddress,<....>
00110019,foo_bar@foobar.com,Foo Bar,<....>,VISA,<....>,999.999.99.99
00110019,foo_bar2@foobar.com,Foo2 Bar,<....>,VISA,<....>,999.998.99.99
00110019,foo_bar3@foobar.com,Foo3 Bar,<....>,VISA,<....>,999.999.98.99
```

Now after less than a second of script run time I have a properly formatted and ready to upload product verification csv file so that par is working just fine. My problem is that I'm wanting to have another script that I will work on later that handles sending out the emails. What I'm trying to do is have this functioning script write another CSV file that is for the email script to use.

The expected output for the email.csv file is like this:

```
Foo Bar,foo_bar@foobar.com,masterSN,copy1sn,<....>,copy21sn
```

But the output I get is like below:

```
Foo Bar,foo_bar@foobar.com,masterSN
copy1SN
<...>
copy12SN
```

and so forth for each order.

I apologize for misunderstanding how the people that have replied meant for me to respond and I do thank them for their responses.

Comment: You will get better feedback if you show a healthy sample of input and your exact desired output.

Comment: order.scv line 1: Foo Bar;Product 1;foo_bar@foobar.net

Comment: expected email.csv line : foo_bar@foobar,net;main_sn;sn_1;..;sn_21

Comment: When people ask for additional information, they are asking you to **update the question**, rather than leaving the information in comments.

Comment: "my script is currently ..." Yikes, don't you see how a small set of sample input, the required output and your current output would much better describe your problem? We won't need to see a 20 field wide record to help you solve the problem. And do you think all of your logic is causing the problem? (maybe), but removing that and testing yourself would help you understand where your code is failing (or not). Good luck.

Comment: AND you're taking a huge performance hit launching all those extra processes with each of `field1=$(...)`. You can use `while read fld1 fld2 fld3 ..... ; do field1=$fld3; field2=$fldN; ..... ; done < $csvFile` and eliminate many process creations.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information needed. Also, I'm writing this code for someone that wants to be able to see what is easily going on.

Comment: Saw your update. You're already using `awk`, why not just filter your first file and create the email file, i.e `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $3,$5,..."Extra text you may need", $7}' file > email_list.txt`. ? Good luck.